# Probability that a normal random variable generates an increasing sequence

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let assume a random variable following a normal distribution.
What is the probability that N successive draws will form an increasing sequence?

I believe the probability can be estimated using Monte Carlo simulation.

I have an intuition about a specific draw, but can't generalize that reasoning: The first draw gives a value of x, so the probability that the second draw is bigger than x is 1-F(x), where F is the PDF. Then the probability for the third draw is again around 1-G(x) where G(x) is the PDF weighted by the previous "1-F(x)".

Is there an analytical way to determine the exact probability?

Comment: You should be able to directly write the conditional probabilities. Given that the first draw was x, what is the probability that the next draw is larger than x? Just do that N times.

Comment: If $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. continuous random variables (they don't have to be normal), then by symmetry each of the possible $n!$ rankings is equally probable, so the probability that they form an increasing sequence is $1/n!$.

Comment: @angryavian : can you please post your comment as answer? I will then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. continuous random variables (they don't have to be normal), then by symmetry each of the possible $n!$ rankings is equally probable, so the probability that they form an increasing sequence is $1/n!$.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a different solution to @angryavian's: let $(Z_n)_{n\leq N}$ be IID standard normal variables. Recall that the cdf $\Phi$ is strictly increasing and continuous and $\Phi(Z_1)\sim \textrm{Uniform}[0,1]$. Thus
$$P(Z_1<...<Z_N)=P(\Phi(Z_1)<...<\Phi(Z_N))=\int_{[0,1]^N}\mathbf{1}_{\{u:u_1<...<u_N\}}(u)du=\frac{1}{N!}$$